# Bluemix Python App runs then crashes and then runs again

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson, visual-recognition

I run this app on bluemix, which only has to run ones. When the app exits, Bluemix thinks it failed, and runs it again. After a couple of crashes it stops.

This is the app.

```
import os
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from os import environ
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3 
import time
start_time = time.time()

visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3(VisualRecognitionV3.latest_version, api_key='*******************')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './test168.jpg'), 'rb') as image_file:
print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.classify(images_file=image_file, threshold=0, classifier_ids=['***************']), indent=2))

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Any way I can make it exit the app without thinking it fails, and repeats itself?

Comment: [OpenWhisk](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/openwhisk/) might be a better Bluemix platform for a short-lived stateless application like yours, instead of OpenStack.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks, ill check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing the application with the `--no-route` flag should disable the health checking and restarts.

```
cf push myapp --no-route
```

Comment: I've already specified that in the manifest.yml and used the set-health-check command.  cf set-health-check appname none